# MBP running El Capitan freezes at login

Tags: macos, performance, login

Since today, my mid 2011 15 in Macbook pro freezes after login on the admin account. The status bar doesn't even appear, nor the desktop icons. Nothing responds and I need to force shutdown to be able to reboot. 
Those are the things I already tried :
- rebooting in safe mode : desktop icons will appear, but everything freezes after a couple of seconds. I believe since safe mode doesn't work the problem is related with the Finder, DS_Store issue, icon issue, or an iCloud issue. So I went to the next step. 
- running the disk utility First aid tool in the OSX recovery tools (reboot+Cmd+R) : It says the disk is OK. 
- running /sbin/fsck -FY in single user mode : the disk seems to be OK. 
I don't know what to try next. Since I really need my computer for the next days, I might go to an Apple store later this week. I would of course be really happy to avoid the costs of that option.

Does any of you have an idea of what I should try next?

**UPDATE**

As Allan suggested, the problem was my drive beginning to fail. I changed it to a ssd and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

On Apple Support Communities I got a helpful answer I will copy here for others. I don't exactly understand what it does exactly.

> Log in as Guest.
>
> This procedure will delete certain temporary and
>   cache files. The files are automatically generated and don't contain
>   any of your data. Occasionally they can become corrupt and cause
>   problems such as yours.
>
> Please back up all data.
>
> Triple-click anywhere in the line below on this page to select it:
>
> `/var/folders`
>
> Right-click or control-click the highlighted line and select `Services ▹ Open` from the contextual menu.*
>
> A folder with the odd name "folders" should open. Inside "folders" are several subfolders, each with a two-character name. Drag all the subfolders
>   except the one named "zz" to the Trash. **Don't delete the subfolder
>   named "zz".** You'll be prompted for your administrator login
>   credentials. Restart the computer and empty the Trash.
>
> * If you don't see the contextual menu item, copy the selected text to the Clipboard by pressing the key combination `Cmd-C`. In the
>   Finder, select
>             `Go ▹ Go to Folder...` from the menu bar and paste into the box that opens by pressing command-V. You may not see what you pasted
>   because a line break is included. Press return.

I have to mention that for now, it solved my primary issue. However, I'm experiencing some extraordinary slow speed on every app up to now. I guess that this might be caused by the missing temporary files that the system is rebuilding.

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your drive is failing.  Run AHT ([Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257))

Basically, power off your MBP, disconnect all of your peripherals with the exception of your mouse and keyboard (if you have them attached), boot your MBP while holding down the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys.

Be sure to check the box that says "Perform Extended Testing"

The utility will take the MBP through a battery of tests.  If there are any failures, it will list them for you.

If you have a hardware issue, this should let you know.  From there, we can proceed.

Comment: For some reason, AHT won't load. If I reboot while holding the D key, it simply boots normally to the login screen. Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: If your MBP came with 10.7 (which it may have) then AHT would be on Disk 2 of your Original Install DVDs.  Do you still have those?

Comment: It came with 10.6. I lost the original disks long ago now. I'll try alt+D as soon as I have access to a power source.

Comment: OK, I did the alt+D trick and I got a apple.com/support -3403D error back.

Comment: There seems to be some charachters missing from that error code.  It should look something like:  `4SNS/1/1/4000000 TL0P-130`

Comment: For the AHT error, I confirm it was -3403D and nothing more. Since the hard drive is now making a faint periodic rattling sound, I won't wait and I'll bring it to the Apple store. Especially since the Time Machine backup won't go further than the "preparing backup" state.

Comment: It seems my suspicions were right.  If you aren't under Apple Care, I have written some posts on how to upgrade your MBP with an SSD: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229372/my-mac-is-getting-really-slow-what-should-i-do/229377#229377  It's something that's quite easy to do.

Comment: I just remembered that I have an old Bootcamp partition laying around so I booted on it and it works just fine. So it seems that the problem is definetely confined in the main accounts files or in the system, rather than being a global hard drive failure.