# 13" MacBook Pro (Mid-2012) failing to fully boot

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup

I have a 13" MacBook Pro (Mid 2012) that is failing to fully boot.

What happens once I press the power button:

- Screen turns on, and the typical boot-up loading screen with the Apple logo appears
- Once the loading progress bar reaches about halfway, the screen goes black
- About 10 seconds later, the login screen appears
- I click on my account, type my password, and press enter

Now this is when the funky stuff begins....

- The computer does not transition from showing the password box to the loading bar
- Sections of the screen are now gray & green and slightly jittery

After roughly 2 minutes of spazzing out with along with the odd colors showing up....

- Screen goes black
- Fan is still fanning
- Repeated beeping noise

Annnddd thats when I hold the power button and come to you fellas for some help

I'm looking to diagnose the problem in order to hopefully fix it,
any help/recommendation/advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

---

The work-around:

Thinking the graphics card might be the problem, I did the following:

- Uninstalled macOS
- Installed Debian without GUI (command-line only)

At the end:

- Laptop does not freeze anymore
- Laptop does not beep anymore
- No more black/green/gray pixels

Comment: Can you boot up to an external drive or boot into recovery mode at all?

Comment: It sounds like your drive is crashing.  See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/238924/119271 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/231920/119271

Comment: Any action requiring a GUI leads to a crash. I am attempting to install a base Debian OS (command-line only), in order to test the graphics card theory. I will look into the hard drive crash possibility if the issue is not resolved. Thanks everyone

Comment: If you want to test the graphics theory, start macOS in single user mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run Apple's built it hardware test, Turn on your Mac, then immediately press and hold the D key on your keyboard. Keep holding the D key until you see the Apple Hardware Test

I feel it could be a graphics card issue because it seems to play up when you  get to the login screen where the computer actually requires the use of the graphics card.

Comment: Unfortunately I ran across the same problem, except this time the jittery blocks were black, when I held D on boot. No beeping this time (likely not RAM issue). Graphics card must be it, gonna test it with a command-line only Linux install. Thanks! Will resolve this post if it fixes the problem