# MacBook Pro 2012, HDD speed 80MB read/write normal?

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, hdd

I have a MacBook Pro 13" (non-retina) from 2012 with a 512GB HDD. I've run some speed test with BlackMagic and those are around 75-80MB/sec for read/write. This seems slow, but maybe this is normal for this configuration.

Are these normal values?

Comment: So I know this is a late response, but I just found this thread today, thanks to a google search for macbook 2012 HD read/write speeds. I got this SanDisk 250GB SSD from an IT expo/convention and timed the different bootup speeds after cloning the original hard drive. Over direct SATA connection, the 2012 Hard drive took 1min 03s to boot up.
Over USB SATA cable, the SanDisk 3D SSD booted up in 27 seconds. So happy I made this change. Next step is to replace the defunct CD drive with a new high-capacity hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

Those kinds of speeds [are to be expected from a MacBook HDD](https://youtu.be/ZoBRNKMWT0k?t=15). For much higher speeds, consider upgrading the HDD to an SSD. (See [Macbook Pro Hard drive speed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/237520/37797))