# Macbook Pro booting time is slow, can someone decode the system.log excerpts in the description to check if this is a software problem?

Tags: macos, logs

So for a month or so my MB has been considerably slow at booting. I tried the OS X hardware test, and the results were fine. Could this be a problem of the hard drive or battery? I don't know.

I found this [this](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23856447#message23856447) post on the Apple forums and did what was required. These are the lines I've copied from Console: http://paste.ofcode.org/RUD8QpHwG22bBy3mUYNCPC

Thanks

---

Device: Macbook Pro mid-2012

Uses Yosemite (10.10.5)

Comment: It is preferred to have information right in the question instead of linking it. Please remove the link and paste the log in your question

Comment: Too long for the description :/ @Hexa

Comment: Did it not let you paste it? Also, are you using an SSD?

Comment: @Hexa: No it didn't. And I'm not using a SSD - though it could really speed up the system, I'm wondering why the Mac has slowed down like this (no change in any hardware since I started using it)

Comment: Well first, I still suggest you paste the log into the question (as code, of course). Don't worry about it being too long; People on Stack Exchange are used to long posts :P. Also, if you're not using an SSD, a ~30 sec. startup time is normal. Though a minute or more is definitely a problem. I will look forward into the log, though it might have to wait ~10 hours because I need to sleep  (Israel timezone ;)). Maybe someone else will help you in the meantime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Mac is getting really slow, what should I do?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229372/my-mac-is-getting-really-slow-what-should-i-do)

Comment: @Allan I don't think it's a dupe; This is a startup issue that seems to be related to software, so the answers on [My Mac is getting really slow, what should I do?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229372/my-mac-is-getting-really-slow-what-should-i-do) aren't the best solution

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  This appears to be a duplicate of a question already asked, I did want to provide you with some feedback and some suggestions.  When asking questions, it's important to provide your specific Mac Model and Year as well as your current OS.   To do a quick check to see if you hard drive is failing, issue the command `system_profiler SPStorageDataType | grep -i s.m.a.r.t`  If you get anything other than `Verified` your drive is failing.  I suspect that this is the cause.

Comment: @Allan: I get the SMART status as verified. So the drive is probably fine?

Comment: Not necessarily.  SMART is a collection of onboard (the drive) diagnostics.  The next step to verify that your drive is good is to use an App like [Disk Drill](http://www.cleverfiles.com/)  (The features you need are provided free)  Use that tool to diagnose your drive.

Comment: @Allan I got his OS info from the log lol but you're right he should add some system info ti the question (Indo add the current OS version) well good night for now ;)

Comment: @Allan I installed Disk Drill - how do I diagnose my drive, it just has options to recover deleted items?

Comment: @Hexa hey, have you managed to find anything via the logs? Thanks!

Comment: Right click on the icons that show up in the top bar (they would be displaying the temp), then select "Get SMART Status"  It's much more detailed than the command line.

Comment: @Allan The SMART details show OK for every attribute of the drive. What can I do now?

Answer (score 1):

When you say a long time, how long do you mean. I have the same MBP and it takes quite a while to boot mainly because I don't have an SSD. So depending on how long it takes to boot or really the speed of the overall OS, its probably due to the hard drive being slow. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Wait so you have an ssd, My mac takes around 4 minutes boot :0