# Mac OS X El Capitan BootCamp doesn't target Windows 10 ISO

Tags: bootcamp

I was trying to install Windows 10 besides my Mac OS X El Capitan. 
I followed the normal steps I found on the Internet, but when I started to apply I got this and no idea what I should do in order to install Windows.

After I click continue, I choose which USB to save the downloaded file on, and then nothing changed; I still can't finish the process of pointing to an ISO image of Windows 10 that I want to install.

[image: Problem]

Note: my MacBook Pro is manufactured I think in 2010/2011.
It's a Core i5, 4GB RAM.

Windows 7 was installed on it besides my El Capitan OS X a month ago, and BootCamp was deleted by my son.

Comment: I'm not a Bootcamp fan.  Personally, I would max out your RAM (8GB for 2010 and 16GB for 2011) install an SSD and run [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and install Win10 there.  If you haven't put in an SSD, I would do that too.  See this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/229377/119271) for specifics

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately your particular Mac does not seem to support Windows 10. You can [check the link here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990) to verify. The last supported version of Windows on your Mac is 8.1.

Some people have had success installing 8.1 and then upgrading to 10, but you will not get Apple supported drivers and installation might be problematic. Unless you have particular reasons for **needing** Windows 10 you may want to stick with Windows 7.

Comment: He should be able to install Win7/8/8.1 then *upgrade* to Win10.  However a clean Win10 is out of the question.

Comment: Many thanks to you, Steve my problem that it(BootCamp) doesn't let me to point to the Windows ISO Image in the first place

Comment: Is the Windows ISO WIndows 10? If so that is the problem. Try pointing it to a Windows 7 or 8/8.1 ISO.

Answer (score 1):

You can in fact enable it.

Copy Boot Camp Assistant.app to a folder (ex: ~/Downloads).
Right-click > Show Package Content
Edit info.plist in a good text editor (Sublime Text 3 for example).
Remove your model from the Win7OnlyModels list.

For example, if you own a macbook pro, this :

```
<key>Win7OnlyModels</key>
<array>
    <string>MacBook7,1</string>
    <string>MacBookAir3,2</string>
    <string>MacBookPro5,5</string>
    <string>MacPro2,1</string>
    <string>Macmini4,1</string>
    <string>iMac10,1</string>
</array>
```

Becomes this :

```
<key>Win7OnlyModels</key>
<array>
    <string>MacBook7,1</string>
    <string>MacBookAir3,2</string>
    <string>MacPro2,1</string>
    <string>Macmini4,1</string>
    <string>iMac10,1</string>
</array>
```

Save and run your custom Boot Camp Assistant.app

Comment: Cool hack, I like it!