# Requirements difference between Yosemite and Sierra

Tags: macos, system-requirements

I have a late-2009 iMac which seems to have held up pretty well, especially since upgrading the RAM to 12GB.

I only fairly recently updated the OS to **Yosemite** after running Lion for so many years.

The OS update my have made my Mac a *little* slower, but if so then not by a great deal. But I could probably do with updating again — to Sierra — as certain programs require a more recent OS than what I have.

I am a bit concerned that running **Sierra** will put too much of a strain on my machine... or **are the requirements not a whole lot different to any other versions of OS X over the last 5 years or so?**

Comment: You upgraded the RAM, did you upgrade to an SSD?  Relevant answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229372/my-mac-is-getting-really-slow-what-should-i-do/229377#229377

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the general requirements as specified by Apple:

[**OS X Yosemite**](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP711?locale=en_US)

> OS X Yosemite - Technical Specifications
>
> General Requirements OS X
>
> v10.6.8 or later
>
> 2GB of memory
>
> 8GB of available storage
>
> Some features require an Apple ID; terms apply.
>
> Some features require a compatible
> Internet service provider; fees may apply.

[**macOS Sierra**](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp742?locale=en_US)

> MacOS Sierra - Technical Specifications
>
> General Requirements
>
> OS X 10.7.5 or later
>
> 2GB of memory
>
> 8.8GB of available storage
>
> Some features require an Apple ID; terms apply.
>
> Some features require a compatible Internet service provider; fees may apply.