# MacBook keeps restaring on startup

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, performance

I have an issue with my 2011 MacBook pro. Everytime I try to booth my MacBook it get stuck at the progressbar. First it goes really slowely and at about half of the progress bar it freezes. After about 10 minutes of being frozen the MacBook restarts and does it all over again.

A week ago I checked the disk on a different machine using a cable to connect it to USB. The disk still works, no problem there.

I tried alot of tips online, like holding the keys for different boot modes. They all do nothing and the problem keeps occurring. I have a backup of all the files, so I can format the disk when needed.

Does anyone have tips of maybe even a solution to make my MacBook work again?

Thanks :)

Comment: Which keys did you hold?

Comment: Pretty much all the combinations found online.

Comment: Gonna need more specifics :/, Did you try all of the following: Option, Command-R, Option-Command-R, Shift-Option-Command-R, Option-Command-P-R, Command-S, Command-V, and D?

Comment: It's a 2011 meaning it's pushing 7 years of use.   I would bet that your drive is failing.  See this [relevant post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229372/my-mac-is-getting-really-slow-what-should-i-do/229377#229377) for a possible solution

Comment: You can verify it's your drive by installing macOS to an external USB drive (flash or HDD; it doesn't matter; it's for testing).  If the problem goes away, it's your drive.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for my delayed reply, I tried all the combinations again. The only combination that did something was Command-V but after running verbose mode nothing happened.