# New HDD or SSD in MacBook with failed hard drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, hdd

I have a mid 2012 non-retina MacBook pro 13" and recently the hard drive failed and needs to be replaced. I sent it in to a local Apple authorized service provider and was given several options for replacement which include a 1TB HDD and a 525GB SSD. The price difference is about $150 and I was wondering if it was worth the upgrade to an SSD. Also, how difficult would it be to replace it myself if I chose to buy it separately considering I've never done anything trike this before?

Thanks,

Amanda

Comment: Hardware recs are off topic, try hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: See this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/229377/119271).  Even though it's specifically about a 2011, It applies to your 2012 as well.

Answer (score 1):

As far as "worth" that is very subjective. The choice given is between a fast SSD drive (but smaller) and a larger HD (but 2x the size). So, it really depends on whether you need more space, or more speed.
Factually, the SSD drive is much much faster and will make your computer seem a lot faster - startup, app opening, file opening, etc. Almost like a whole new computer.

Can you do it yourself? If you are not afraid of using some small screwdrivers, sure you can. It requires some really small jeweler screw drivers, a plastic "spudger" or small plastic tool to unlodge a connector or 2. Some of the connectors are *really* small, so you have to be very careful to not force them. But it's not anything normal humans can't do. Here's a link with some sbs instructions.

https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Hard+Drive+Replacement/10378