# Finder error after taking screen shot, apple button not working either

Tags: macbook-pro

So I've had this macbook pro for maybe 4-5 years and I think it's on its way out. Startup is sluggish as hell, I cannot open EVE Online Launcher or Steam at all, Microsoft Word hangs on startup, Chrome sometimes beachballs and I can't even open the right-side options menu, and I cannot click the Apple icon on the upper left without spinning-ball every single time (hence why I cannot even check what version I'm on!)

I've reset NVRAM, but it fixed nothing.

Is there anything left I can do that doesn't involve replacing physical components?

EDIT: Taking a screenshot made Finder go unresponsive.
[image: Activity Monitor]

EDIT2: after another crash from clicking the apple button
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Kindly consider [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/341392/edit) your question to specify certain crucial details such as make and model of your MacBook Pro, any hardware changes that you may have made and the version of macOS running. This will help in getting quick and relevant answers.

Comment: sounds like it is fighting a severe bacterial infection (to many non Apple apps). It needs some serious cleaning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Mac is getting really slow, what should I do?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229372/my-mac-is-getting-really-slow-what-should-i-do)

Comment: for some reason unknown to me some others think it is justified  to just close (reject) your question rather than trying to help you. At the same time they down voted my attempt to help you,

Comment: Welp, guess that's how it is, probably just my laptop dying then.

Comment: Which MacBook?  What version of macOS?  How much memory?  Did you back up your data and try a fresh install?  We can't even begin to speculate until we have a point from which to start theorizing.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) We'd love to help you, but I'm with @Allan on this - the question really does miss key details. Besides the *MacBook* tag you've used, we have no idea on the exact model, it's specs (CPU, RAM, Drive), what version of macOS you have installed, the amount of free drive space you have, have you installed any new software/hardware recently, do you have a backup (Time Machine or otherwise), and so on. Also, besides resetting the NVRAM, have you tried anything else? If so, what? Answering these questions will make it a lot easier for people to help you.

Comment: Also, a 4 to 5 year old MacBook is not synonymous with a dying machine. I've got MacBooks and MacBook Pros that are over 10 years old that still work well and continue to serve a purpose. So please don't give up and assume your machine is dying - unless of course you're looking for an excuse to upgrade! :)

Comment: It's a mid 2013 macbook pro, the one with the dvd drive, but I have no clue what version it is and since clicking the apple logo locks up the computer, there's no way I can check what version I am right now. Also 8gb memory. Have a time machine backup from quite a while ago, can still make one if I have the time.

Comment: Try booting into Safe Mode (hold Shift while booting) or even Recovery Mode (Cmd-Opt-R)

Comment: I will try that, last time I tried safe mode locked up the laptop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, lets do this.

In Terminal run `launchctl list` to see all programs running.

Then anything that does not start with `com.apple....`

Quit or Delete and make sure it is not in you Login items (automatically starts when you log in)

Check your CPU load and Memory load in Activity monitor.

Gaming sites like Steam might run limits on your GPU.

Lets close and quit all 3D party apps, like coconutBattery and others.

The goal here is obvious. Free you OS X and see how it runs then.

Since your Finder just crashed, Open the Console and select Errors and Faults, then take screen shot and publish.

Comment: So everything I see that isn't Apple I close? Will try but how do I quit those I don't see in the force close menu?

Comment: @PaulS.D. I don‘t see how this could help, actually. According to your screenshot your system is mostly idle anyway, so killing processes will do more harm than good.

Comment: @PaulS.D. we will discuss how to close those once you found them. So you did not like my answer and down voted it ? So be it, I am out then.

Comment: I'm brand new so my upvote doesn't count

Comment: The apps do not have to be high CPU consumers to create problems as @nohillside is saying. In principle anything that was not developed and tested by apple can create problems. That is why it is recommend to quit them for testing purpose. And your mac is not old at all.