# DIY replacement of DVD drive with an SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, upgrade, remote-disc

I have a late 2011 15" MacBook Pro. It has a 750 GB HDD and I'm about to upgrade the RAM from 2x4 GB to 2 x 8 GB.  I am looking for do-it-yourself resources/guides to either (depending on difficulty):

1. replace the HDD with a SSD (obviously the easier scenario if not too difficult, or, ...)
2. a) Remove the internal DVD drive that hardly ever gets used.
   b) Install the DVD drive in an enclosure with a USB or Thunderbolt port for use as an external device when needed.
   c) fill the empty DVD drive space with an SSD and make use of both the HDD (for data) and the SSD (for OS and software).

Obviously the first question is readily dooable and I'm considering the Samsung 860 EVO 1 or 2 TB if I settle on the first upgrade scenario.

Question 1:
I'm just not sure Samsung 860 EVO will fit?

Question 2:
It is really the second scenario that I need the step by step guide for, if it is possible, not overly difficult and, if any of you folk know of a good DIY resource?

Comment: The Samsung SSD will fit as it is the size of a standard 2.5” drive.  The replacement is super easy; see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/229377/119271

Comment: Thanks Allan and Klanomath.  Looks like I'm on the right track.  Your feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Two sites that are very Mac friendly are the [iFixit site](https://www.ifixit.com) and the [OWC (Other World Computing)](https://www.owcdigital.com) site. OWC sells SSDs and many other Mac upgrades. I suggest you search the site for what you are looking for.

An iFixit example guide how to install a second HDD/SSD (with links where to buy all required parts and tools):

[Installing MacBook Pro 15" Unibody Late 2011 Dual Hard Drive](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Unibody+Late+2011+Dual+Hard+Drive/10986)

Comment: 2nd OWC. I did this exact thing to my 15" MacBook Pro, back in the day. Yes, an 860 EVO will fit. Any 2.5" SATA SSD will fit. Once you install macOS on the SSD, you can move the location of your home folder to the slower, more spacious HDD. The end result, the OS/System files/applications are on the fast SSD, everything else on the HDD, seamlessly. https://www.lifewire.com/move-macs-home-folder-new-location-2260157 *** BACK UP EVERYTHING BEFORE PROCEEDING***

Comment: And don’t forget to activate TRIM for the SSD after you installed it.

Comment: To everyone,  thanks very much, looks like I joined the right group.