# MacBook Pro 13 June 2012 Boots Into Internal HDD Instead of External USB

Tags: hard-drive, usb, startup

The background:

Last week I booted up my Macbook Pro 13 June 2012 edition. But the machine turned off midway on the apple loading screen. I did the First Aid on Disk Utility using command + R and it came with disk exit error 8. I was recommended to wipe the hard drive and reinstall Mac OS El Captain but I still got the same error while reinstalling.

So I installed it on my 16gb external hard drive which worked but when I pressed the boot-up option button, I only see my internal hard drive (HDD). I also opened the Startup Disk option which shows the external hard USB drive but instead of booting into the external USB hard drive, it goes back to the MacOS installer page (the internal HDD).

How can I fix this?

Comment: That means your install was not finished properly on the external drive.  But instead of doing that, why not just change out the internal drive?  It's a standard 2.5" HDD.  See this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/229377/119271

Comment: Thanks, Allan, I want to get an SSD, is there a specific type for Macbook Pro?

Comment: Any 2.5" will work.  See the link.